# .match Array value is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, match

I'm calling the .string method on a string and setting that equal to another variable. It returns an array with the `[match value, index, and input]`.
When I try to refer to the second element in the array, it comes back as undefined. Can someone tell me why that is? Heres my code:

```
var str = "hello world"
var matchArray = str.match("ell");

=>matchArray  = ["ell",index:1,input:"hello world"]

var index = matchArray[1];
console.log(index);

=>undefined
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `matchArra`y returns only `["ell"]` without the index

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "hello world"
var matchArray = str.match("ell");
```

`matchArray` is an `Array` but in javascript as we know we can set properties in array as well as it's an object.

In the above case, `matchArray` has only the mathces in the array. but the other properties such as `index` and `input` are in the object.

If you do `console.dir(matchArray)` you would get the properties as well.

So to access those properties use object's notation like `matchArray.index` or `matchArray.input`

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much!

Comment: I am sorry. I forgot this.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is an interesting language. Although the matchArray **object** is indeed an array, in JS you can add new members to any **object**.  So, matchArray is an array of length 1, but it also has the members index and input defined on it.  Try this:

```
...
console.log(matchArray.index);
console.log(matchArray.input);
```

We could define a similar object from scratch like this:

```
var hybridObj = [ "ell" ];  // It's an array
hybridObj.index = 1;        // With props
hybridObj.input = "hello world";
```